# How to view line between container and dragged element when I dragging an item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The task is:
when I drag item from container I need to show line connected container with item. When I drop item - line disappears. So I need just some advices or link in which direction to look for solving.(I use js, angularjs).

```
<div layout='row'
  <div dragula='"first-bag"'>container1
     <div>
        Item1 
     </div>
  </div>

  <div dragula='"first-bag"'>container2
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be a bèzier curve, or can it be straight?

Comment: Also, can you use js?

Comment: I can use js. angularjs.
bèzier curve -need.in case if it's not possible we can use straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A <s>good</s> way would be to create a canvas element between the 2 elements and draw a curve on it:

CSS

```
.curveCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

JS

Here I assume you have 2 elements, from is the element the curve starts from and to is where the curve goes to (the draggable element.

```
var from = document.getElementById("from");
var to = document.getElementById("to");

// Create the canvas element
var c = document.createElement("canvas");

c.style.top = from.offsetTop + "px";
c.style.left = (from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth) + "px";
c.style.width = (c.width = to.offsetLeft - from.offsetLeft - from.offsetWidth) + "px";
c.style.height = (c.height = to.offsetTop - from.offsetTop) + "px";
c.className = "curveCanvas";

// Draw the curve

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(c.width / 2, 0, c.width / 2, c.height, c.width, c.height);
ctx.stroke();

document.body.appendChild(c);
```

This creates a canvas between the 2 elements and draws a curve on it.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/d7s9w6k4/

Comment: thank you.are you sure it works?can you privode with some working example? I don'ts see line when drag item

Comment: @Serhiy I fixed it up a bit once I got home